# Android SQLite: Failing to update records

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I'm developing a small app that keeps records of places and the categories they belong to. For now, I'm just working on the category table and once I manage to perform all CRUD operations, then I'll advance to the rest of the app.

Problem is, I managed to insert, delete and read from that table but I can't update. I've got this code:

DBAdapter:

```
...
    public boolean updateCategory(long rowId, String name) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_ID_CAT, rowId);
        args.put(KEY_NAME_CAT, name);
        return db.update(TABLE_CATEGORY, args, KEY_ROWID_CAT + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
...
```

---

my EditCategory class:

```
public class S7_EditCategory extends Activity {

    EditText et_name_category;
    private Context ctx;
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.s7_edit_categories);

        et_name_category = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_category);
        ctx = this;

        final String nome = getIntent().getStringExtra("nome");
        final long id_cat = getIntent().getIntExtra("_id", 0);

        et_nome_category.setText(nome);

        Button button_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button_save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {

                    String new_cat = et_name_category.getText().toString();
                    DBAdapter dbadap = DBAdapter.getInstance(ctx);
                    dbadap.updateCategory(id_cat, new_cat);

                    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, S5_Categories.class);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                    finish();

                    }

                    catch (Exception ex) {

                        throw new Error("some error");
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Logcat tells me that ( _id = 0 ) so, I think it has to do with the parameter passed on from the previous activity, Category:

```
public class S5_Categories extends ListActivity {

    private Context ctx;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.s5_categorias);
        ctx = this;

        fillList();         
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View view, int position, long id) {

                Cursor c = (Cursor) parentView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Intent i = new Intent(ctx, S7_EditCategoria.class); 
                i.putExtra("nome", c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("nome")));
                i.putExtra("id_cat", c.getColumnIndex("_id") + 1);
                startActivityForResult(i, 0);

            }
        });
    }

    private void fillList() {
        try {

            DBAdapter dbadap = DBAdapter.getInstance(ctx);
            Cursor c = dbadap.getAllCategorias();

            String[] from = new String[] { "nome" };
            int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c, from, to,
                    SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {

            throw new Error(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(requestCode) {

        case 0:
            if (data != null) {

                DBAdapter dbadap = DBAdapter.getInstance(ctx);
                Cursor cursor = dbadap.getAllCategorias();
                adapter.changeCursor(cursor);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

well, can someone help me please?
Thanks in advance
Chiapa

---

Ok, now I managed to get that parameter id, but I still get errors when updating: as I try, I get an error like:

error updating name=hospitals id_cat=4 using UPDATE category SET name=?, id_cat=? WHERE id=4

please help

Chiapa

Answer (score 1):

try the following way

```
db.update(TABLE_CATEGORY, args, KEY_ROWID_CAT + "=?", new String[] { (rowId) });
```

instead of

```
db.update(TABLE_CATEGORY, args, KEY_ROWID_CAT + "=" + rowId, null)
```

Why do you want it as a `int`. Is their any valid reason. I didn,t find any reason from the code you are provided. If their is no valid reason means change your method as like as following.

```
public boolean updateCategory(long rowId, String name) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_ID_CAT, rowId);
    args.put(KEY_NAME_CAT, name);
    db.update(TABLE_CATEGORY, args, KEY_ROWID_CAT + "=?", new String[] { (rowId) });
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for your response but,
it won't work as my method returns a boolean and that is an int

Comment: No, I found that the problem isn't the method itself, but the parameters I can't pass from the Categories class to the EditCategories class. I don't know why the id isn't passed as I can pass the name of the category.

I made toasts with the value of the id_cat variable and it's always zero, that's why it doesn't work. Can you help?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78073392/Chiapa_App.rar

here is my app, can you help? thanks again